# Update package in conda-forge, when uploader is "conda-forge"

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pypi

I uploaded a Python package to PyPi. Some time after, I decided to try to upload it also to conda-forge, and I discovered that it was there already: 
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cmapy

This is a nice surprise, but I would like to understand how this happens, who uploaded the package? (maybe an automatic script?), and, how can I update my package in conda-forge when it is updated in PyPi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The repositories for conda-forge follow the pattern `https://github.com/conda-forge/<package>-feedstock`. You can go to that GitHub page to see the conda recipe and update it there. Most often, conda-forge is running a web service that will (try to) automatically bump the version of the recipe when a new version is released on PyPI. You can also update the version manually by making a pull request to the appropriate feedstock repository.